# Getting Error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: element not interactable

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

when i am trying to loop the second tab getting element not inractable error.
Can any one sole this issue here i have attached my source code

I have tried this below code once the test 2 is PASSED getting error for test 3

i am getting this error due to which scenario and i have tried some of the paths but i didnt get any solution please help on this

```
@Test(priority =2)
public void AdditemsinDrycleanBag() throws InterruptedException {
//  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//  System.out.print("Enter Item name with single quote in Dry Clean: " );
//  String Item1 = sc.nextLine();
//  Thread.sleep(1000);
//  d.findElement(By.xpath(item + Item1 +")]")).click();
//  while(true) {
//      if(Item1.equals("Close")) {
//          break;
//      }
//      else {
//          System.out.print("Enter Item name with single quote in Dry Clean: " );
//          String Item = sc.nextLine();
//          d.findElement(By.xpath(item + Item1 +")]")).click();
//      }
//  }
    while(true) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Item name: " );
        String Itemname = sc.nextLine();    
        if(Itemname.equals("Done")) {
            break;
        }
            else {
                d.findElement(By.xpath(Searchitem)).sendKeys(Itemname);
                d.findElement(By.xpath(item)).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                d.findElement(By.xpath(Searchitem)).clear();
                d.findElement(By.xpath(bag2)).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                d.findElement(By.xpath(bag1)).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    d.findElement(By.xpath(bag2)).click();
    
}

@Test(priority =3)
public void AdditemsinWashandSteamBag() throws InterruptedException {
    while(true) {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Item name: " );
        String Itemname1 = sc1.nextLine();  
        if(Itemname1.equals("Done")) {
            break;
        }
            else {
                d.findElement(By.xpath(Searchitem)).sendKeys(Itemname1);
                d.findElement(By.xpath(item)).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                d.findElement(By.xpath(Searchitem)).clear();
                d.findElement(By.xpath(bag3)).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                d.findElement(By.xpath(bag2)).click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    d.findElement(By.xpath(bag3)).click();
    
}
}
```

Comment: Post the URL and the full code of the specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Add explicit wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("your locator")));
Perform the action to the element
```